# Powershell Regex Complex Pattern (XML)

Tags: regex, xml, powershell, select-string

I have a string in an XML which I am trying to retrun to a varable (below).

```
<XMLElement><![CDATA[TEXT - I - FIND - INTERESTING]]></XMLElement>
```

My problem is that I have no knowledge of regex and I am finding it difficult to understand how to convert my special characters into a "string" which is not interpreted as a regex charater.

The text between the square brackets can be any length and any charachter; this is what I would like to save to my variable e.g. "TEXT - I - FIND - INTERESTING".

I am also wondering if this is actually the best approach to this problem.

Any support would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know Powershell, but maybe.... https://regex101.com/r/FEumVc/1. The text of interest would be in group 1.

Comment: @MDR thank you. I will update my question with the answer. This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text() function is nice.  Here's another way.  Even if the node isn't at the top, this should work.

```
get-content -raw file.xml | select-xml '//XMLElement' | 
  % { $_.node.'#cdata-section' }

TEXT - I - FIND - INTERESTING
```

Note that tags would be ignored in a cdata section.  Example:

```
'<script>
  <![CDATA[<message>Welcome to TutorialsPoint</message>]]>
</script>' | select-xml '/script' | % { $_.node.'#cdata-section' }

<message>Welcome to TutorialsPoint</message>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex for XML!

Working with XML in PowerShell has the advantage that we can use XPath to search and navigate a document. In your case I would use the `text()` selector to resolve the inner value of the CDATA section:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<root>
    <XMLElement><![CDATA[TEXT - I - FIND - INTERESTING]]></XMLElement>
</root>
'@

$interestingString = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//XMLElement/text()').Value
```

`//XMLElement` means "find and `<XMLElement>` *anywhere*"

Comment: Is there a way to select just the text from an attribute?  This just returns nothing:  `"<XMLElement attrib='this'></XMLElement>" | select-xml '/XMLElement/@attrib/text()' | % node`

Comment: @js2010 no, the expression has to resolve a "node set", in this case consisting only of the `<![CDATA]>` node

Comment: Thanks Mathias, that works a treat and something I can understand better what I am looking at :)